# How to check cpu consumption by a python script

Tags: python, psutil

I have implemented kalman filter. I want to find out how much of cpu energy is being consumed by my script. I have checked other posts on Stackoverflow and following them I downloaded psutil library. Now, I am unaware of where to put the statements to get the correct answer. Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   #kalman code
    pid = os.getpid()
    py = psutil.Process(pid)
    current_process = psutil.Process();
    memoryUse = py.memory_info()[0]/2.**30  # memory use in GB...I think
    print('memory use:', memoryUse)
    print(current_process.cpu_percent())
    print(psutil.virtual_memory()) #  physical memory usage
```

Please inform whether I am headed in the right direction or not.
The above code generated following results.

```
('memory use:', 0.1001129150390625)
0.0
svmem(total=6123679744, available=4229349376, percent=30.9, used=1334358016, free=3152703488, active=1790803968, inactive=956125184, buffers=82894848, cached=1553723392, shared=289931264, slab=132927488)
```

Edit: Goal: find out energy consumed by CPU while running this script
    ​

Comment: [current process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.times), [other process](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_times)

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it clearer exactly what information you’re trying to get? With a vague question, all we can really do is point you in different vague directions, and explain why you might, depending on exactly what you want, be sort of on-track but wandering off it, or heading in completely the wrong direction.

Comment: @abarnert I have edited the question. Please check again

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you're trying to find the peak CPU usage during execution of that `#kalman code`, or the average, or the total, or something else?

But you can't get any of those by calling `cpu_percent()` after it's done. You're just measuring the CPU usage of calling `cpu_percent()`.

---

Some of these, you can get by calling [`cpu_times()`](http://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_times). This will tell you how many seconds were spent doing various things, including total "user CPU time" and "system CPU time". The docs indicate exactly which values you get on each platform, and what they mean.

In fact, if this is all you want (including only needing those two values), you don't even need `psutils`, you can just use [`os.times()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.times) in the standard library.

Or you can just use the [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/time.html) command from outside your program, by running `time python myscript.py` instead of `python myscript.py`.

---

For others, you need to call `cpu_percent` *while your code is running*. One simple solution is to run a background process with `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures` that just calls `cpu_percent` on your main process. To get anything useful, the child process may need to call it periodically, aggregating the results (e.g., to find the maximum), until it's told to stop, at which point it can return the aggregate.

Since this is not quite trivial to write, and definitely not easy to explain without knowing how much familiarity you have with multiprocessing, and there's a good chance `cpu_times()` is actually what you want here, I won't go into details unless asked.

Comment: How do I print it? print (os.times)?

Comment: @pinkpuffles You have to call the function and print the result, not print the function itself, so `print(os.times())`.

Comment: It gives the time consumed. I am looking for the energy. Though given power, it canbe found

Comment: @pinkpuffles That information basically doesn't exist anywhere. You can get a rough approximation of it from CPU time spent, by measuring energy for your specific server machines and calibrating it against times and curve-fitting, which is (last I checked—a few years ago…) how CDNs and some other massive-scale hosts end up charging for consumption costs.

Comment: @pinkpuffles The reason you can't do better than heuristics is that modern CPUs have things like speed boost, smart idling, variable TDP, heuristic-driven SDP, hyperthreading, etc., so the amount of energy it takes to do a certain amount of work is tremendously context-dependent.

Comment: @pinkpuffles On newer chips, you _can_ read the energy used by each component over a given timespan, but there's no way to figure out how to charge that to a specific process except by doing _that_ side of things heuristically.